# Не запускается Tomcat на Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat

Не запускается Tomcat на Intellij IDEA, пишет ошибку Application Server not specified. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Ну, так выберите сервер в выпадающем списке `Application server` или сконфигурируйте новый нажав на кнопку `Configure`